# Is libclang slower than using clang driver based tool?

Tags: c++, autocomplete, llvm, clang, llvm-clang

I am writing an autocompletion and syntax tool using `libclang`. I am pretty much using the same code as in `c-index-test.c` file. But the speed of results is very slow. There are few non libclang  clang tools which works faster than my libclang tool.

Is there any optimization I can do to get results faster? My code is pretty much as follows:

```
CXIndex cidx = CreateIndex(0,0);
TU = clang_parseTranslationUnit(Cidx, 0, argv, argc,0,0...);
```

and so on.

Even the very first time I run clang tool, they seem to be faster.

Codebase I am working is huge.

Comment: Before you try to optimize the code, you have to figure out where the bottleneck is exactly. I recommend you use a profile like `valgrind` or similar. Then you can be more specific in your question, if you will still have any.

Comment: I talked to one of the core developers of clang, and he said that using the clang binary tool is slow, and one should really use libclang for autocompletion because "that's where all the optimizations are done" to speed up completion.

Comment: There's some shenanigans the standalone clang compiler tool uses, for example never free'ing any memory, since they know the tool is going to compile a single TU and then exit.

The optimizations in libclang are going to be more useful if you do multiple queries on a single TU. They're things like parsing header files once, so you can edit the buffer and then code complete multiple times.